# Is it possible to use the Android Hardware without using android APIs?

Tags: root-access, hardware, development

I've always liked cheap smartphones ($ 50) because with little money I can have a powerful system with lots of sensors and things like that. So I wondered if it was possible to use the hardware without using the very limited android APIs, programming it at a low level then, of course with the root. In particular I wanted to see how the LTE module worked and experiment with this having full control, the Android API does not allow it to do much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using NDK. It gives more access to android hardware.

Please refer

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53134098/hardware-access

Comment: Can you add a description of the answer you linked to?

Comment: Thanks. Also, asking for votes is a very bad idea (it usually causes *down*votes).